# What triggered the mass "Late answer" review queue?

Tags: support, moderation

There's 200+ late answers in the queue, I started looking at them and all the ones I saw were answered a while ago (a few months to a year). They're not recent at all and some were even upvoted many times already. It's interesting to note many answers seem valid as well

Any idea what's going on ?

[image]

Comment: Fortunately as people review them it's reducing, we're down to a queue of ~45 now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to have been a network-wide event, as expats also had a lot (percentage-wise).  I presume it's a script that's identified a subset of answers on each site based on some criteria (some seem to contain question marks, for example?), and then they're being raised for re-review. It's quite a clever way really of cleaning up some old answers.

It's been discussed on meta.SE:

[Why did the late answer queue spike on Sep 29, 2015?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267081/why-did-the-late-answer-queue-spike-on-sep-29-2015).

Answer (score 3):

It would appear to be the result of a change in policy on what gets Late Answers sent to the review queue.

It used to be answers by users with a reputation of less than 10 after a certain time had elapsed on the question.

[On 29th September the reputation threshold was raised to 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080), meaning a lot more answers were destined for the queue.